# How to load a node js swagger.json with basic authentication

Tags: node.js, swagger-ui, window.onunload

I am using a node express framework with basic authentication .The function `app.get('swaggerjson'{}` also falls under the same app.js running nodejs.

Due to which swagger UI is unable to load the swagger.json especially in chrome .

How can I either exclude a specific get function from node basic authorization or provide a basic authorization (username and password), while defying swaggerUibundle in `window.load` function .

Comment: Easier way is to encode the creds and pass it in the Authorization header.  Sample refer https://davidbeath.com/posts/expressjs-40-basicauth.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment ,but i have many route(with header etc) in the app and i just need to exclude only one out of using the basic auth function .

Comment: You should be able to skip auth or setup basic while registering routes, can you post the code ?

Comment: Can we see where you registered you routes and middleware?

Comment: Node js auth code

Comment: Nodejs AuthCode
----
app.use (function(req, res, next) { Conditionx XXX }
Swaggeer Get Function 
-------
// serve swagger
app.get('/swagger.json', function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(swaggerSpec);
});
Swagger Json definition in DIST of swagger UI
--------
window.onload = function() {   // Build a system   const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({     url: "http://host1:443/swagger.json",     dom_id:  '#swagger-ui',    deepLinking: true,     presets: [